# findout the datatype of values by comparing two different collections

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a collection

`IQueryable<Parameters>` lstparams which is a return type of GetparamsforanApp() function.
Parameters is a class type

```
public class Parameters
   {
       public string Name { get; set; }

       public string Type { get; set; }

   }
```

Now there is an another function named **startApp** where in `Dictionary <string,object>` paramslst as an i/p parameter.

Now in this startApp function i need to compare the user i/p ie paramlst with lstparams
ie it needs to check whether the user is giving proper key value pair for the function

this is for validation purpose...

conclusion:
Need to compare each item of paramslst ie Dictionary type with lstparams
compare means need to verify the Key and the datatype of Value in the dictionary matches with the Iqueryable result returned from GetparamsforanApp() function and notify the user  which parameters were incorrect if doesnt match ie(if Key in dictionary doesnt match with Name property in Parameters class or datatype of Value in dictionary is not equal to Type in Parameters class for the respective Key)

Comment: I'm not sure I totally get this, but I'm sure I'm just tired. Could you show us the method that's getting called, where you want the validation to occur? And an example of an invalid input, and one of a valid one?

Comment: StartApp(Dictionary<string,object> paramslst) is the method should be called .Now inside this method there is another method which needs to be called is GetparamsforanApp() which has returntype of IQueryable<Parameters> ,now need to compare the paramlst to the queryable result returned from GetparamsforanApp() to check if the the Key and the datatype of Value of each item in the paramslst were matching with the queryable result returned from GetparamsforanApp

Comment: The phrase "**in** a nutshell" usually means you are about to summarize in the fewest words possible. Is there any chance you might be able to re-phrase that last paragraph because it confused me more than helped?

Comment: @Enigmativity pleae see the updated qustion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the following:

```
IQueryable<Parameters> theParams;  // list of parameters
Dictionary<string, object> paramsList;
```

If I understand your question correctly, you want to create a dictionary from the `IQueryable`, using the `Name` as the key and the `Type` as the value.

```
var paramsDictionary = theParams.ToDictionary(parm => parm.Name, parm => parm.Type);
```

Then, go through the `paramsList` dictionary and look up each key in the `paramsDictionary`, and check the type.

```
foreach (var kvp in paramsList)
{
    string typeName;
    if (!paramsDictionary.TryGetValue(kvp.Key, out typeName))
    {
        // error: key isn't in parameters list
    }

    // Get the type of the object in the dictionary
    Type objectType = kvp.Value.GetType();
    if (typeName != objectType.Name)
    {
        // error: type names don't match
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jim appreciate your help!!,this works after making small change to last few lines ie Type objectType=kvp.Value.GetType(); if(typeName!=objectType.Name){}

Comment: @shiv455: Glad you got it working. And thanks for the corrections. I've fixed the code in my answer.

Comment: Hi Jim,typeName is returning null always...Please help

Comment: @shiv455: If `typeName` is `null`, then either the type name is `null` in the parameter definition, or the key wasn't found in the dictionary.